# Передача разнотипных параметров через Dictionary<string, object> C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Я учусь разрабатывать под Windows Phone с несколькими страницами, при переходе между которыми необходимо передавать именованные строковые параметры, среди которых могут оказаться массивы. Допустим:

```
["token"] = "Токен", ["id"] = [ "Идентификатор1", "Идентификатор2"]
```

Мой фрагмент кода в Page1.xaml

```
string token;
string[] id;
var navParams = new Dictionary<string, object> { ["token"] = token, ["id"] = id }
Frame.Navigate( typeof(Page2), navParams );
```

Использую вторым параметром `object` вместо `string` для того, чтобы можно было пропихнуть массив.

Фрагмент кода в Page2.xaml - вызывает ошибку:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var navParams = e.Parameter as Dictionary<string, object>;
    string token = navParams["token"] as string;    //Исключение
    string[] id =  navParams["id"] as string[];    //Исключение
```

Пробовал `ToString()` и через `Convert`, все равно не помогает. Временно решил проблему путем сериализации в строку через `Join`,`Split` и `Dictionary<string, string>`, но думаю что можно сделать код лучше.

Comment: А какое исключение? Подробности в студию! Тип исключения и stack trace.

Comment: (И кстати, почему dictionary, а не просто класс с двумя полями?)

Comment: Исключение `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` типа `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Таких страниц, а следовательно и возможных переходов между ними достаточно много, параметры почти всегда строковые. Мне показалось что для такой задачи именованный массивчик лучше подходит.

Comment: Что находится в `e.Parameter` в методе `OnNavigatedTo`? Поставьте брейкпойнт и посмотрите во время выполнения.

Comment: Тогда понятно, а какой реальный тип `e.Parameter`? У вас наверняка `navParams == null`, а вы почему-то не проверяете.

Comment: Научился использовать точки останова =) Действительно, допустил ошибку, в e.Parameter попадало значение другого класса а не `Dictionrary`. Хоть и ошибка была по глупости, все равно не зря задал вопрос. Пришлось точки останова освоить - это оказывается очень удобная штука)

Comment: @Олег: Вот и хорошо :)

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать

```
string token;
string[] id;
var navParams = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>> { ["token"], token], {"id", { id }}}
Frame.Navigate( typeof(Page2), navParams );
```

или

```
object[]
```

Comment: Подчеркивается `["token"] = token` Не удается неявно преобразовать string в string[]. С `object[]` тоже самое

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать так var navParams = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(); navParams.Add(token, new string[] {id});

Comment: Не могу понять этот код. У нас же должно быть название параметра и сам параметр. Тут получается в качестве названия параметра значение токена, а в значении идентификаторы. Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: ["token"] - это ключ, token - это значение, нужно ...Add("token", token). Как я понимаю

Answer (score -1):

```
string token = navParams["token"] as string;   //Исключение //здесь вообщем то Ваш массив строк, который вы пытаетесь запихнуть в переменную типа string и в результате получите InvalidCastException.
string[] id =  navParams["id"] as string[];    //Исключение // ну а здесь доступ по не существующему ключу и в результате KeyNotFoundException.
```

Инициализация:

```
var navParams = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { token, id } };
```

Получение значения по ключу:

```
string[] id = (string[])navParams["token"];
```

Comment: Непонятно с чего минусуете, есть замечания? Ну так велкам в комментариях.